# ¿Cuál es el proceso por el que una palabra debe pasar para que su uso sea aceptado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Para explicar mejor mi pregunta, en el lenguaje oral y escrito existen ciertas palabras, como por ejemplo "haiga", que no son aceptadas por ser vulgares, en este caso, la palabra que doy como ejemplo, es bárbaramente vulgar. Existen otras palabras que se usan en sustitución, malamente o a veces por descuido, de la palabra que se debería usar.

No obstante, hay palabras, que siendo consideradas vulgares en algún tiempo pasado, pasan a formar parte del lenguaje y viceversa, como la palabra que doy como ejemplo en el párrafo anterior, ya que, por lo que he escuchado, la palabra "haiga" tuvo un uso valida siglos atrás en sustitución de la palabra "haya", del verbo haber, la que hoy se usa, aunque hoy esa palabra "haiga" es un sustantivo y su origen data, de acuerdo a lo que he leído, de principios del siglo pasado, cuando durante el Boom del Caucho en el Perú los dueños de las empresas, obviamente millonarios, que extraían caucho en la selva decían "Lo que 'haiga'", de forma despótica, cuando se les consultaba por la marca de carro que deseaban, y es por esa razón que "haiga" se usa para nombrar a una persona que teniendo mucha riqueza material tiene un habla prácticamente de analfabeto, pero volviendo al presente, el uso de esa palabra es muy usado, la he escuchado a mucha gente decirlo, inclusive gente famosa y hasta presidentes, como por ejemplo el señor Alejandro Toledo, ex presidente de Perú, cuando, siendo presidente, en una entrevista se le escapo esa palabrita y fue duramente criticado. ¿Es posible que el uso de estas palabras, en la función que estas palabras están siendo usadas, incorrectamente, pasen a formar parte de nuestro lenguaje en el futuro? ¿Cuál es el proceso formal por la que una palabra que se usa incorrectamente tiene que pasar para que esto ocurra, que sea aceptada como palabra correcta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entendiendo que te refieres a "ser aceptada" por la Real Academia Española.

El conjunto de los [académicos](http://www.rae.es/la-institucion/los-academicos) se reúne regularmente en los [Plenos](http://www.rae.es/la-institucion/organizacion/pleno-y-comisiones), para poner en común las propuestas de las diferentes comisiones, y tomar decisiones sobre ellas.

El proceso de actualización de un diccionario se centra en las siguientes tareas:

- La adición de nuevos artículos o acepciones.
- La supresión de artículos o acepciones ya existentes.
- La enmienda total o parcial de los artículos.

En cuanto a incluir (adición) palabras usadas por el pueblo, y que tradicionalmente se consideraban incorrectas:

> Las comisiones académicas elaboran las propuestas de adición,
>   supresión o enmienda que posteriormente examinará el Pleno para
>   decidir sobre su aprobación. El Instituto de Lexicografía prepara los
>   materiales que se discuten en comisión y documenta las propuestas. Una
>   vez estudiadas por las comisiones y el Pleno, las propuestas pasan a
>   consulta de las academias americanas que propondrán sus observaciones
>   para que la modificación pueda ser aprobada definitivamente.

Para más detalles, consulta este artículo: [Cómo se actualiza el diccionario](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/como-se-hace-el-diccionario)

Comment: Esto es indiscutible, como lo que pasó en Chile con la palabra "huevón" (no sé si en otro país se adicionó). Sin embargo, el enfoque de mi argumento está direccionado a la aceptación de una palabra dentro de un contexto, es el ejemplo del presidente. Ahora, reitero mi posición, la función de los diccionarios es mantener un orden para mantener una comunicación y una fluida y comprensiva. Inevitablemente, por la forma de desarrollarse, socialmente las palabras son aceptables o no.

Comment: @AlejandraRiveraRebolledo Tu respuesta me ha parecido excelente (por eso la he votado), porque sea cual sea la expectativa de la pregunta, es interesante que haya diversidad de enfoques en las respuestas.

Comment: Creo que para comprender cómo se habla, hay que entender y dimensionar cómo funciona la lengua en la sociedad y que sí está permitido cambiar palabras, crear otras (una palabra que cumpla con las reglas gramaticales, dentro de un contexto en el cual se entienda su significado, es una palabra aceptable como nueva). En lo personal no conozco los criterios que se usan para "formalizar" una palabra, sin embargo, sí conozco el proceso social en el que van transformándose y adaptándose en su progreso (estudio y análisis hecho por gusto). Gracias por tu comentario :)

Answer (score 4):

En el español existen los fenómenos fonéticos, estos son sustituciones, sustracciones o adhesiones de sonidos a las palabras.

Por ejemplo: *T"oalla - to**ba**lla." "Zanahoria - zana**do**ria." "Aguja - a**b**uja*," etc.

Ahora, tomándolo desde el punto de vista de la historia del lenguaje, podemos ver que a medida que se van construyendo sociedades, nos vamos encontrando con una mayor necesidad de comunicarnos, es por esto que no podemos dejar de lado algo sumamente importante, que en nuestra actualidad, lo tenemos inmerso en nuestra forma de hablar: *"la economía y la comodidad"*. Actualmente, para comunicarnos buscamos economizar el tiempo que nos demoramos en hablar o escribir, simplificando o acortando las palabras.

Por ejemplo: *"información - inf. (se dice "info" cuando se expresa oralmente)" "etcétera - etc." "departamento - dtpo.*" y así.

Esto sin perder el significado de lo que se está diciendo. La comodidad al hablar, nos lleva a, que en el momento de pronunciar todas las palabras que construyen las oraciones, algunas de las letras sean suprimidas, remarcadas, se le agregue complementos directo o indirectos a las oraciones, produciendo una repetición innecesaria (no incorrecta).

Otro punto que debemos comprender es que toda lengua va evolucionando a medida que van cambiando las generaciones, se agregan nuevos conceptos, se eliminan otros, por ejemplo: *"Botica - farmacia"*, *"setiembre - septiembre."* (En Chile por lo menos) etc.

Las pronunciaciones también se van moldeando según el contexto sociocultural, socioeconómico en el que se va desarrollando la persona. La forma de hablar y expresarse de una persona de estrato social alto no es la misma que la de uno bajo (conste, no estoy discriminando), ya que sus contextos sociales son diferentes y son absolutamente determinantes al momento de aprende a hablar, escribir, pronunciar, etc. Es por esto que una forma de pronunciar una palabra se puede catalogar de "correcta" o "incorrecta" porque socialmente es aceptado así y no de otra forma, independiente de lo que puedan decir los diccionarios, estos solo nos ayudan a mantener un margen de "orden" en la lengua española.

Así como el latín vulgar se fue masificando y moldeando según la mezcla con las lenguas de los pueblos conquistados, podemos ver actualmente que la lengua española va sufriendo transformaciones. En América Latina no hablamos como la lengua nativa de España y en ambos lugares se habla español.

Sabemos que desde que la Reina Isabel de Castillas declaró el castellano como lengua dominante, construyendo así una gramática para esto, a lo largo de los años han habido reformas que van amoldándose a los nuevos hablantes. Esto dentro de un proceso que puede tardar años.

Tenemos a la R.A.E quien nos determina cómo deben escribirse y pronunciarse las palabras, y dentro de ese margen van surgiendo los cambios fonéticos mayoritariamente, como lo mencionaba anteriormente.