# ¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar una palabra del DRAE?

Tags: historia, rae, dle

Resulta que me da por buscar en el diccionario la palabra *[despavorido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DIELxzf)* (usada en expresiones como *huir despavorido*), y me encuentro con que es el

> Participio del antiguo *despavorir*, "sentir pavor".

Me llamó la atención lo de "antiguo", y efectivamente, dicha palabra no viene recogida en el diccionario. La busco en el [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) y la palabra aparece en todas las versiones desde 1780 hasta 1992, siendo la versión de 2001 la primera en la que la palabra ya ha caído en desuso y ha sido eliminada.

Así que la pregunta que me surge, tras otras en sentido inverso que hablan sobre la inclusión de palabras ([1](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13257/12637), [2](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17317/12637)), es la siguiente: ¿cómo decide la RAE qué palabras o acepciones deben retirarse del diccionario? En su página web, la RAE afirma que el proceso de actualización del diccionario consiste en

> - La adición de nuevos artículos o acepciones.
> - La supresión de artículos o acepciones ya existentes.
> - La enmienda total o parcial de los artículos.

Es ese segundo paso el que me intriga. ¿Cuántos años deben pasar desde que una palabra deja de usarse hasta que desaparece del diccionario? ¿Cómo se sabe que ha dejado de usarse? ¿Se eliminaría igualmente si aún se siguiera usando en el habla?

Comment: Se decide por votación de los acádemicos. No hay un período de tiempo establecido

Comment: No tenía idea que borraran palabras. ¿Y qué significa desuso? ¿Que la palabra despavorido ya fue borrada de todos los textos y toda la literatura en la que se usó? Entonces las nuevas generaciones que lean esos libros no van a tener la referencia.  No me suena muy lógico.

Comment: @DGaleano el término _despavorido_ curiosamente sí sigue recogido, lo que se ha eliminado es el verbo del que procede. Supongo que pensarán que si estás leyendo un texto de 1850, usarás un diccionario de 1850.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Las palabras no se eliminan *nunca*. Solo por desuso las palabras que salen del diccionario se transfieren al "[Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico)", que es un diccionario de diccionarios, tal y como se describe en la propia página de la RAE.

Sólo las muy antiguas, "en general anteriores al siglo XVI", según explica la máxima autoridad de la academia, Blecua, pueden pasar del diccionario general al histórico, pero siguen estando. Su desuso tiene que comprobarse en largos períodos de tiempo.

No obstante, se pueden eliminar definiciones de palabras como se hizo con:
**FEMENINO. Débil, endeble.
MASCULINO. Varonil, enérgico**

A eso se refiere con la supresión de artículos o acepciones ya existentes.
Te paso un par de páginas con mas información:

- [¿Se pueden eliminar palabras de la Real Academia de la Lengua?](http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2012/08/120802_cultura_palabras_dicccionario_rae_judiada_rechazo_retiro_jrg.shtml)
- [La RAE elimina acepciones machistas](http://www.cubadebate.cu/noticias/2013/12/24/la-rae-elimina-acepciones-machistas/#.V6EO6bgrI2w)

Comment: Las palabras que salen del diccionario se transfieren al "Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico", que es un diccionario de diccionarios, tal y como se describe en la propia página de la RAE.

http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico

Comment: @David ¿Te molestaria si complemento mi respuesta con esta informacion que has proporcionado?

Comment: Para nada, para eso lo había puesto para complementar tu respuesta :)