# ¿Cómo se decide si una palabra se tiene que marcar como "en desuso" o eliminarla del diccionario?

Tags: definiciones, rae, dle

Al hilo de una charla que acabo de mantener con un colega del trabajo, formulo esta pregunta relacionada con *[¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar una palabra del DRAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17437/12637)*

Todo ha venido a raíz de la palabra *gambesón* ("saco acolchado que llegaba hasta media pierna y se ponía debajo de la armadura"). La definición está sacada del DLE de 2001 porque en la versión de 2014 (o puede que en la actualización de 2017), y a pesar de existir en el DLE desde 1884, esta palabra ha desaparecido del diccionario. Eliminada. Lo que me extraña es que en ningún momento ha estado marcada como "en desuso". Y más me extraña que se haya eliminado teniendo en cuenta el auge que hay con el tema de las recreaciones medievales: [aquí tenéis una web](https://www.tienda-medieval.com/es/184-gambesones) donde venden gambesones.

Así pues, ¿cómo se decide si una palabra se debe marcar como "en desuso" o si se debe eliminar del diccionario?

Comment: Un otro ejemplo, la palabra [*adempribio*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/?val=adempribio) existe en el DLE 2001 (sin marca de `"des."`), pero no en la versión corriente.

Answer (score 5):

En un [artículo de la BBC](http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2012/08/120802_cultura_palabras_dicccionario_rae_judiada_rechazo_retiro_jrg)

José Manuel Blecua, director de la Real Academia Española de la Lengua dice:

> Cuando se demuestra que una palabra no se usa, cosa que es muy difícil, se la marca como desusada, pero no se elimina

Y añade:

> Sólo las muy antiguas, en general anteriores al siglo XVI pueden pasar del diccionario general al histórico, pero siguen estando. Su desuso tiene que comprobarse en largos períodos de tiempo.
>
> Pero así como se certifica su uso, también se señala su decadencia. Para ello se utilizan dos abreviaturas para puntualizar que el término ya no se utiliza o que es antiguo.
>
> - La abreviatura "desus." (desusadas).
> - Las marcadas como "ant."
>     (anticuada), por la cantidad de años que llevan sin utilizarse ahora
>     sólo aparecen en el Diccionario Histórico.