# ¿Alguna vez ha eliminado/cambiado la RAE la definición de una palabra por petición?

Tags: rae, dle, lenguaje-peyorativo, diccionarios

Encontré este artículo sobre la etimología del término *negro* en su sentido de "escritor fantasma":

[Negro no es esclavo. Iniciamos campaña para que la R.A.E. elimine o corrija la definición de la expresión negro literario](https://afrofeminas.com/2018/09/16/negro-no-es-esclavo-iniciamos-campana-para-que-la-r-a-e-elimine-o-corrija-la-definicion-de-la-expresion-negro-literario/) (*afroféminas.com*)

Pensé yo que era análogo al término inglés "**ghost**writer", i.e. que *negro* significaba aquí *oscuro, oculto*; pero me equivoqué - de hecho, es un calco del término francés, una metáfora por una relación esclavista/esclavo entre el autor nombrado y el autor de verdad:

> La expresión es de origen francés -los anglosajones usan el término ghostwriter, escritor fantasma- y surgió con la producción en masa de folletines en el siglo XIX, cuando se empezó a llamar négrier -negrero- al que firmaba y nègre -negro- a quien escribía.

El sitio del artículo ha lanzado una campaña en Change.org para que:

> ... tanto los medios periodísticos, como literarios y académicos, dejen de utilizar el término “negro” para lo que define la RAE como “Persona que trabaja anónimamente para lucimiento y provecho de otro, especialmente en trabajos literarios” **y que la propia RAE introduzca en su acepción el carácter claramente racista de la expresión o la elimine definitivamente.**

No quiero empezar un debate sobre cuál debería ser la posición de los diccionarios, ya sea en la prescripción del lenguaje, ya sea en la descripción de cómo habla la gente. Sin embargo, pero me pica la curiosidad sobre:

#### ¿Alguna vez ha eliminado o cambiado la RAE la definición de una palabra de su diccionario por petición?

<sub>Nota: no me refiero aquí a los casos de:</sub>

<sub>- palabras cuyas definiciones se han cambiado por las propias investigaciones/decisiones de la propia RAE</sub>

<sub>- palabras eliminadas después de siglos de [desuso](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23968/c%C3%B3mo-se-decide-si-una-palabra-se-tiene-que-marcar-como-en-desuso-o-eliminarla) [etc](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17437/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-proceso-para-eliminar-una-palabra-del-drae?noredirect=1&lq=1) sin discusión del público contra su inclusión</sub>

Comment: Relacionado (y potencial respuesta a esta pregunta) [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar una palabra del DRAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17437/5481). En la respuesta aceptada: '**Las palabras no se eliminan nunca**. Solo por desuso las palabras que salen del diccionario se transfieren al "Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico", que es un diccionario de diccionarios, tal y como se describe en la propia página de la RAE.' Se enlaza por cierto a una artículo que recuerda que la RAE es "notario de la lengua": **cuando una palabra ingresa al diccionario de la RAE ha iniciado un camino sin retorno**

Comment: Relacionado: [*Un abogado pide a la RAE que la palabra «moro» se considere una acepción racista*](https://www.abc.es/cultura/20140113/abci-abogado-moro-racista-201401131659.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, existen situaciones recientes en las que la RAE ha actualizado entradas del diccionario por petición o presión social.

Un caso reciente en el que han **modificado**, que no eliminado, una entrada es acerca de una de las acepciones de "fácil":

> La Real Academia Española (RAE) ha modificado, tras la petición de numerosos ciudadanos anónimos, famosos a través de redes sociales y asociaciones y colectivos la quinta acepción del adjetivo "fácil", que se refería a la "*mujer* que se presta sin problemas a mantener relaciones sexuales". A partir de ahora, esta calificación *no se referirá solo a las mujeres sino a toda "persona*", han confirmado este miércoles [Marzo de 2018] fuentes de la institución.
>
> Extraído del artículo: [La RAE elimina la acepción de “fácil” referida a la mujer que “se presta al sexo sin problemas”](https://elpais.com/cultura/2018/03/14/actualidad/1521038565_584340.html): 'La definición se cambia a "persona" ante las peticiones de particulares, famosos y asociaciones'

Es notable destacar que, como recoge este otro artículo "[La RAE se niega a eliminar la polémica acepción de «mujer fácil»](https://www.abc.es/cultura/abci-mujer-facil-rae-201801261002_noticia.html)"

> La Real Academia Española (RAE) «mantendrá la línea de **no censurar** el diccionario»

Estos cambios no reflejan sino una serie de actualizaciones para, [según bbc,](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2013/11/131127_diccionario_espanol_rae_vocablos_sexistas_amv) "evitar que uno de los libros más consultados en español, cuya primera edición se publicó en 1780, sea un baluarte del machismo moderno" entre los que se incluyen también, según dicho artículo

- femenino, cuya sexta acepción incluía "Débil, endeble"
- [babosear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4j1B0EW): que ha pasado de ser "obsequiar a una **mujer** con exceso" a "Hacer demostraciones de obsecuencia excesiva."
- [gozar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JNbAlxi) dejaría de significar "conocer carnalmente a una **mujer**"

Estos son ejemplos de palabras que han sufrido recientemente un cambio en algunas de sus acepciones por decisión de la RAE.

Acerca de eliminar entradas del diccionario, estas **no se eliminan nunca** (Como queda explicado en una pregunta previa del stack: [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar una palabra del DRAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17437/5481)). Extraigo libremente del artículo [¿Se pueden eliminar palabras de la Real Academia de la Lengua?](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2012/08/120802_cultura_palabras_dicccionario_rae_judiada_rechazo_retiro_jrg)

> la Real Academia Española de la Lengua rechazó una solicitud para quitar la palabra *[judiada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MZsFLE5)* del diccionario
>
> Si el uso de la acepción está documentado, se verá reflejada en el diccionario. La institución se considera a sí misa "un mero notario de la lengua". No promueve, ni legitima, ni desaconseja el uso de una palabra. Sólo [sic] lo recoge.
>
> **"Cuando se demuestra que no se usa, cosa que es muy difícil, se la marca como desusada, pero no se elimina"**, explica a BBC Mundo José Manuel Blecua, director de la Real Academia Española de la Lengua.
>
> Desde la RAE insisten en que este traslado de un compendio a otro sólo [sic] tiene su raíz en el uso y no en otras cuestiones. Para José Manuel Blecua, director de la RAE "no hay palabras molestas u ofensivas; todas las palabras tienen una categoría léxica dentro del diccionario como piezas que son dentro de la lengua".

Esos compendios que se citan son el diccionario y el tesoro lexicográfico

> Las palabras no se eliminan nunca. Solo por desuso las palabras que salen del diccionario se transfieren al "Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico", que es un diccionario de diccionarios, tal y como se describe en la propia página de la RAE.
>
> Fuente: [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar una palabra del DRAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17437/5481)

Comment: Opino que no hace falta poner "[sic]" al _solo_ adverbial con tilde. Su uso sigue siendo opcional (obligatorio cuando hay ambigüedad, según el DPD). Además, la sugerencia contra su uso aún genera resistencia y, si no recuerdo mal, la misma RAE le ha quitado fuerza.